# Текст на странице pdf файла занимает 2/3 листа, как его уменьшить чтобы он помещался на половину листа?

Tags: python, pdf

Есть текст программы которая из pdf файлов вырезает верхнюю половину страницы и склеивает результаты. Изменился вид документа, теперь он занимает не половину а 2/3 страницы, по идее надо уменьшить текст и задействовать тот же код

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PageMerge
import re
import os
TEMPLATE = re.compile('Документ.*\.pdf')
PATH = r'D:\1'
RESULT = 'concatenated.pdf'
SCALE = 0.9
HALFPAGE = 400  
VIEWRECT = (0, 0.03, 1, 0.53)
def get2(pages):
srcpages = PageMerge()
if len(pages) > 1:
    for p in pages:
        srcpages.add(p, viewrect=VIEWRECT)
        srcpages[-1].scale(SCALE)
    srcpages[1].y = HALFPAGE
else:  
    srcpages.add(pages[0], viewrect=(0, 0.03, 1, 1))
    srcpages[0].scale(SCALE)
return srcpages.render()
def scale_pdfs():
files = [n for n in os.listdir(PATH) if TEMPLATE.match(n)]
files.sort()
pages = sum((PdfReader(os.path.join(PATH, fn)).pages for fn in files), [])
writer = PdfWriter(RESULT)
for i in range(0, len(pages), 2):
    two_pages = get2(pages[i: i + 2])
    writer.addpage(two_pages)
writer.write()
if __name__ == '__main__':
scale_pdfs()
os.system(RESULT)
```

Comment: Замените значение переменной `SCALE` на `0.5`; `HALFPAGE` на `300`. Поексперементируйте.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, промежуточный результат получился, после измененя строк
SCALE = 0.45
HALFPAGE = 400  
VIEWRECT = (0, 0, 1, 1). В таком варианте ничего не срезается, но большие пустые поля вокруг текста. Завтра еще по экспериментирую. Еще раз спасибо.